# Missing /etc/hostname files

Tags: server, ssh

I am fairly new to Linux and I am setting up a server.

Anytime I use "sudo" command, I get "Unable to resolve host".

When I ssh into my server I have a certain hostname, let's say "bob". when I check hosts file with cat /etc/hosts I dont see bob name anywhere.

/etc/hostname does not exist. I am not sure what either file is supposed to say.

Please assist.

Comment: In terminal just do `echo "yourWantedHostName" | sudo tee /etc/hostname` just make sure you have no spaces in your hostname

Comment: Just did it, still showing unable to resolve.

Comment: What does `echo $(hostname)` return ?

Comment: As far as I know, `sudo` doesn't require a set hostname

Comment: I ended up reinstalling with a newer version of Ubuntu and the problem is solved. Thanks guys.

Comment: should have been `"echo '127.0.0.1 your_hostname' | sudo tee /etc/hostname` Better ,use hostnamectl to set hostname `sudo hostnamectl set-hostname $new_hostname`

Answer (score 0):

To set a host name use hostnamectl

```
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname $new_hostname
```

If you can not use sudo, boot to recovery mode , remount your root partition rw, and then run the above command.

FYI the default format is $ip_address $host

```
127.0.0.1 bob
```

Or whatever you want.